# Event when controls have Width and Height

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need the **actual** `Width` and `Height` of controls in Xamarin.Forms (which are inside a `StackLayout`).

I thought I could get that in the `OnAppearing` method, but they are still both `-1`.

So when/how do I get the actual `Width` and `Height` of controls in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check them within [`OnSizeAllocated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated?view=xamarin-forms) method , then they wont be -1

You can override that method too.

Comment: Thanks. Also `SizeChanged`.